# How to while loop stop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I input some thing from the list and when it done I want to exit the loop.

How can I exit the loop in the following code written in python?

```py
while True :
    name = input()
    d = int(input())
    for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
        if list[i] != name:
            print("Wrong")
        else:
            q = list[i+1]-d
            print(q)
            break
```

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic but your code is incorrectly [indented](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp#:~:text=Indentation%20refers%20to%20the%20spaces,indicate%20a%20block%20of%20code.). This code would fail to run. And it is pretty horrible to read.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can check if the input name is in a list and exit loop if there is found...

```
list = ["Pepe", "Luis"]

while True:
   name = input ("Name? ")
   if name in list:
      break
```